# Is it possible to have implicit Ordering[Option[T] and Ordered[Option[T]] at the same time in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicits

My code:

```
import Ordered.orderingToOrdered
import java.util.Date

val (d1, d2) = (Option(new Date()), Option(new Date()))
d1 compare d2
```

result with -Xlog-implicits:

```
Information:(268, 5) math.this.Ordering.Option is not a valid implicit value for    
     scala.math.Ordering[Option[java.util.Date]] because:
     diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[Option[java.util.Date]]
     starting with method ordered in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits
        d1 compare d2
        ^

Information:(268, 5) math.this.Ordering.comparatorToOrdering is not a valid implicit      
    value for scala.math.Ordering[Option[java.util.Date]] because:
    diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[Option[java.util.Date]]
    starting with method ordered in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits
        d1 compare d2
        ^

Error:(268, 5) diverging implicit expansion for type  
    scala.math.Ordering[Option[java.util.Date]]
    starting with method ordered in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits
    d1 compare d2
    ^
```

I think what happens here is a cycle between Ordered and Ordering - implicit Ordering[Option[Date]] is in scope because it's defined in object Ordering and it it is a subclass of java.util.Comparator, so you can use it to create another ordering...

This is compiled against scala 2.10, it seems that there were changes in this area in 2.11, but scalac entered infinite loop when I tried to upgrade scala.

Edit: 
Just to show I'm not clueless, I fixed it for the time being with substituting `import Ordered._` with my `import OrderedFix._`:

```
/** Avoid implicit cycles between scala Ordered and Ordering */
trait OrderedFix[T] {
    def compare(that :T) :Int

    def < (that :T) = compare(that) <0
    def <=(that :T) = compare(that) <=0
    def > (that :T) = compare(that) >0
    def >=(that :T) = compare(that) >=0

}

object OrderedFix {
    implicit def ordered[T :Ordering](self :T) :OrderedFix[T] = new OrderedFix[T] {
        def compare(that :T) = implicitly[Ordering[T]].compare(self, that)
    }
}
```

But this is silly, that's what the stdlib should provide...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the `Ordered` trait is considered bad style by many people. The preferred way is to stick to the `Ordering` type class. The following is an example of using just `Ordering`:

```
val (d1, d2) = (Option(new Date()), Option(new Date()))
val ord = Ordering[Option[Date]]
import ord._

compare(d1, d2)

d1 < d2
d1 equiv d2
```

Here the `import` both gets you function `compare` into scope as well as extension methods that allow the infix operators shown in the last two lines.

Comment: Well, this is good if I was only to compare a single type instantiation. Unfortunately I have quite a lot of that in my current code for various tuple and collection types, and it would result in more implicit declaration and import lines than the ordering code itself, so my solution is infintely more practical. Also, I find compare as an infix operator much more readable in case of tuples/longer expressions.

Comment: And what's wrong with Ordered? I mean beside the design glitch which doesn't allow me to control which I want to use? The way I always understood it, Ordered was a logical property of an object, often implemented either directly or by providing the conversion in the companion object. If my class has a natural, intuitive ordering, than it's better because this order can be abailable as default all the time and substituted only when needed.

Comment: On the other hand, I have to explicitly declare or import Ordering as well as Ordering#Ops to use them, meaning that client code has to know where to look for the ordering even if it doesn't care about it's actual semantics, only that sorting permutations will always return some normal form, so I used it mainly when it was not widely used around the program and different implementations where possible.

Comment: The problem of `Ordered` is that you have to convert each element, unless a type already mixes in one specific `Ordered`. The idea of `Ordering` is that you can in most cases have different types of orderings (e.g. think of a reversed ordering). A type class is more clean because an ordering usually is something not inherent in the thing to order. I advise you not to fall for an "infintely more practical". Just pass the same instance of the ordering around.

Comment: With Value classes no runtime conversion is needed.

Comment: `Ordered` does not extend `Any`, so this will never be a [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the ambiguous implicit conversions by using the `Comparable` method `compareTo`:

```
import Ordered.orderingToOrdered
import java.util.Date

val (d1, d2) = (Option(new Date()), Option(new Date()))
d1 compareTo d2
```

(I still recommend the `Ordering`)